# Add OpenCV3 for Anaconda3 not working in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, installation, anaconda

Listing the installed packages in anaconda active environment, I can see the opencv3 as in this image:

[image]

but when I try to `import cv2`, it fails

> ImportError: No module named 'cv2'

Comment: Did you activate the environment into which OpenCV is installed?

Comment: I am using the default environment, so this is not the issue

Comment: Just to check, if you do `which python` is it in the same `bin` directory as the `conda` program that you did `conda list` with?

Comment: `which python` gave me `/usr/bin/python` ... I did conda list in the terminal without specifying any folder...